# Video Game game modes patent eligible?

Tags: patentability

I read an article saying among us could have patented their imposter game mode.

I also found patent by microsoft that is literally a game of tag but with cars. here is a video link to it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtLQtK4uZyw&list=LL&index=14

heres the actual patent

https://patents.google.com/patent/US7497776

so a game mode that hasn't been done can be patented?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a moving target. There were some older software related patents that currently would not be considered patentable. I am not a lawyer, but in principle I think a novel game play design might well be patentable but it needs to achieve all the normal requirements. These are being novel which something new, non-obvious which means someone skilled in the field wouldn't see it as an obvious thing to do and useful which a game should qualify as. As I said, I'm not a lawyer and there are some important legal decisions that impact software patentability so I wouldn't base any decisions to pursue a patent on my answer.